# Unable to make boxfile (or open tiff) in Tesseract

Tags: ocr, tesseract, leptonica

I'm following [these instructions](http://michaeljaylissner.com/blog/adding-new-fonts-to-tesseract-3-ocr-engine) for training the Tesseract OCR engine for a new font.

However, when trying to make the box file, I get an error. This is the command I use:

```
H:\Documents\TesseractTraining>tesseract eng.helvetica.exp0.tif eng.helvetica.exp0   batch.nochop makebox
```

And here is the error message:

```
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.02 with Leptonica
TIFFstream: Sorry, can not handle image.
Unsupported image type.
```

Some googling suggests that there might be an error with the Leptonica installation. I don't even know if Leptonica is installed on my computer and the webpage is quite confusing with several READMEs (one called "[README](http://www.leptonica.com/source/README.html)" and one called "Documentation"), none of them simple enough for me to understand how I would make it work on Windows. I have the Express Edition of Visual Studio 2008, so I can't use the command prompt suggested.

So, my question is: Does anybody know what might be wrong and how I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you got a bad image. You can use [jTessBoxEditor](http://vietocr.sourceforge.net/training.html) tool to create TIFF images suitable for training purpose.

Comment: Shameless plug, but... I've also created a program that does this (generates box file+TIFF) written in Qt - https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-trainer/

Comment: jTessBoxEditor does not give a good tiff.. did this solution work for you? any options were added to get the correct tiff file? When i run batch.nochop makebox i get error tessdata_manager.SeekToStart(TESSDATA_INTTEMP):Error:Assert failed:in file ..\..\classify\adaptmatch.cpp, line 555